# Spring @Controller Separating GET and POST mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with annotation configuration.  I have a controller class for handling HTTP GET calls:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{table}/{identifier}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEditView(ModelMap map, @PathVariable String table, @PathVariable Object identifier) {
        //generate the view for this record
    }
```

and a Controller for processing form submits on that URL

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormSaveController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{table}/{identifier}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveView(WebRequest request, @PathVariable String table, @PathVariable Object identifier) {
        //save the updated values and redirect to view
    }
```

When I attempt to startup my container, spring complains

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'FormSaveController' to URL path [/form/{table}/{identifier}/edit]: There is already handler of type [class com.company.web.FormController] mapped.
```

This seems to indicate what I'm trying to do is not supported in Spring. The reason I am trying to separate the controller for generating the form from the controller saving the form because I am using Springs `@ExceptionHandler` to handle any runtime exceptions that occur, and I would like to handle an exception for displaying the view differently than an exception for saving a record.

Is there a different way of handling what I am trying to do (utilize Springs `@ExceptionHandler` annotation for specific kinds of request?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I am trying to separate the controller for generating the form from the controller saving the form because I am using Springs `@ExceptionHandler` to handle any runtime exceptions that occur, and I would like to handle an exception for displaying the view differently than an exception for saving a record

I would imagine that your view template engine would throw exceptions of a different type hierarchy than exceptions encountered while saving records in your datastore. It may be easiest to place these methods in the same class, and then just address your `@ExceptionResolver` concern by mapping exceptions of the view engine's type one way, and DB exceptions another.

Comment: I ended up reworking the exception hierarchy so that each exceptional event is much more distinct.  I also used Spring's `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` to convert all data-access related exceptions into sub-exceptions of `DataAccessException`.  So now I have a couple of `@ExceptionHandler` methods for the custom exceptions, and one for the data-access related exceptions (like inserting/updating a record in the database)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using in the same Class? I think that would work.  If you wish to use ExceptionHandler then try [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers)